# Relation between subsets of a power set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Relations are defined on a power set $P(\Bbb N)$

1. A~B, if A\B is finite
2. A~B, if $A\Delta B$ is finite
3. A~B, if $A\cap B$ is finite

Show if 1),2) and 3) are reflexive, symmetric or transitive.

First I assume that A and B are subsets of $P(\Bbb N)$ and R would be the relation between both sets...

For 1) A\B = $\{x | x \in A\text{ and }x \notin B\}$  Since xRx is not fullfilled, this is not a reflexive relation? I don't know if i understood it correctly ..If someone could quickly point it out!

Thanks

Comment: In number $1$, $A\sim A$ holds if and only if $A\setminus A=\{x\mid x\in A\text{ and }x\notin A\}$ is a finite set. But $A\setminus A$ is the empty set. Is the empty set finite? Yes! So then $A\sim A$ definitely holds in 1 for every $A$.

Comment: If the relations are on P(N) then A,B are members of P(N), not subsets of P(N).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [list of set identities and relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_identities_and_relations) on Wikipedia could be helpful.

1. $A \sim B$ if and only if $A \setminus B$ is finite.

- Reflexive ✔️ $A \setminus A = \varnothing$ is finite
- Symmetric ✘ Let $A = 4 \mathbb{N} = \{ 4, 8, 13, \ldots \}$ and $B = 2 \mathbb{N} = \{ 2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots \}.$ Then $A \setminus B = \varnothing$ but $B \setminus A = \{ 2, 6, 10, \ldots, \} = 2 + 4 \mathbb{N}.$
- Transitive ✔️ Assume $A \setminus B = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_m \}$ and $B \setminus C = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}$. Want to show that $A \setminus C$ is finite. Let $x \in A \setminus C.$ If $x \not\in B$ then $x \in A \setminus B = \{ a_1, \ldots, a_m \}$ while if $x \in B$ then $x \in B \setminus C = \{ b_1, \ldots, b_n \}.$ Thus $A \setminus C \subseteq \{ a_1, \ldots, a_m, b_1, \ldots, b_n \}.$

2. $A \sim B$ if and only if $A \triangle B$ is finite.

- Reflexive ✔️ $A \triangle A = \varnothing$ is finite
- Symmetric ✔️ Because $A \triangle B = B \triangle A$ so one side is finite if and only if the other side is finite.
- Transitive ✔️ Because $A \triangle C = (A \triangle B) \triangle (B \triangle C) \subseteq (A \triangle B) \cup (B \triangle C)$ (see [list of identities here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_set_identities_and_relations)) where the right hand side is a finite set when $A \sim B$ and $B \sim C$ are true.

3. $A \sim B$ if and only if $A \cap B$ is finite.

- Reflexive ✘ $A \cap A = A$ so if $A = \mathbb{N}$ (for example) then $A \cap A$ is not finite so $A \sim A$ is false.
- Symmetric ✔️ Because $A \cap B = B \cap A$ so one side is finite if and only if the other side is finite.
- Transitive ✘ Let $A$ be an infinite set (for example, $A = \mathbb{N}$), let $C = A,$ and $B = \varnothing.$ Then $A \cap B = \varnothing$ is finite and $B \cap C = \varnothing$ is finite but $A \cap C = A = C$ is infinite.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for this, however i have a little question, I see for many proofs you need to suppose a set is finite, for example for 1)in order to prove transitivity you assumed that $A\B $is a finite set from $a_1 to a_m$, but what if it were an infnite set? Is there a way to prove for the general case?

Comment: Assuming definition (1) of $\sim$ is used, the case where $A\setminus B$ is an infinite set (equivalently, the case where $A\sim B$ does not hold) is not relevant for transitivity, which is the statement: "IF $A\sim B$ and $B\sim C$ then $A\sim C$." So to prove transitivity, you must assume that both  $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus C$ are finite. There is no need to consider the case where one or both of these sets is infinite. Also, I do not understand what you mean by the general case.